# How to get first position in Listview, if i don't have getter and setter methods

Tags: java, android, listview

here's my adapter class

```
public class MenuAdapter extends HeaderListAdapter implements
            View.OnClickListener {

        private View v;
        private int selPos = 3;
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                .getAssets(), "OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");

        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
                .getAssets(), "OpenSans-Bold_0.ttf");

        // ======
        @Override
        public View getHeaderView(int pos, View cv, ViewGroup vg, Object o) {

            View v = cv;
            if (cv == null)
                v = LayoutInflater.from(vg.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.menu_header_row, vg, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(o));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            textView.setTypeface(font1);
            textView.setTextSize(19);
            return v;
        }

        // ===
        @Override
        public View getItemView(int pos, View cv, ViewGroup vg, Object o) {

            final Object n = o;
            v = cv;
            if (cv == null)
                v = LayoutInflater.from(vg.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.menu_item_row, vg, false);

            String[] separated = String.valueOf(o).split("-");

            // Log.v("adapter value", String.valueOf(o));
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(separated[0]);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textView.setTypeface(font);
            textView.setTextSize(19);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            View vi = mDrawerList.getChildAt(pos - mDrawerList.getFirstVisiblePosition());
            Log.v("log", vi+"");

            if (pos == 1) {

                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } 
            else {
                imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(separated[1]));
            }
            v.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
            v.setOnClickListener(viewListener);
            v.setTag(pos);

            if (pos == selPos && (pos != 1 && pos != 16)) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2980b9"));
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }

            return v;
        }

        // ===
        @Override
        public View getCustView(int pos, View cv, ViewGroup vg, Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Object n = o;
            v = cv;
            if (cv == null)
                v = LayoutInflater.from(vg.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.menu_custom_row, vg, false);

            EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            editText.setHint("Search");
            editText.setTypeface(font);
            editText.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

            return v;
        }

        // ===
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

        private OnTouchListener touchListener= new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2980b9"));
                return true;
            }
        };

        private OnClickListener viewListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method

                //ba.notifyDataSetChanged();
                selPos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            //  displayView(selPos);

            }

        };

    }
```

here in get itemview, at first position of listview, need to update its image.
but this image sets to multiple positions while i'm scrooling. 
plz check the code at if(pos = 1) {  // do change  }

Comment: What do you mean in "get first position"? Do you want to retrieve View object or you want to retrieve data object?

Comment: i'm trying to add few modification at first position of list, i'm using if(pos == 1){// do chanes }.  but changes reflects at multiple positions. while i'm scroling.

Comment: ok, do you want to get first object from list or first Visible object from list?

Comment: If you want to get help on this site spent some time to explain your problem. There are 3 answers for you, but none of them really can help you. To understand what problem is, I need to ask several question. Please respect people who spent their time to help you.

Comment: oK, what are the questions?

Comment: Explain what you want. Edit you question and add code of your activity where you working with listView. Add code of your adapter (if you using custom adapter). Describe what you want to achieve and what you've already tried.

Comment: @Demand do u need any thing else ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public static void ensureVisible(ListView listView, int pos)
{
if (listView == null)
{
    return;
}

if(pos < 0 || pos >= listView.getCount())
{
    return;
}

int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

if (pos < first)
{
    listView.setSelection(pos);
    return;
}

if (pos >= last)
 {
    listView.setSelection(1 + pos - (last - first));
    return;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pos` to fetch whichever position you want from your list.

In your adapter:

```
if (pos == 1)
    Object item = getItem(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
```

maybe this one helps..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please, be a little bit more verbose when you answer. Explain what your solution achieve.